# Laravel Model Average of Non-N/A Values

Tags: laravel, average, models

I am looking for the best way to average the values of a submodel in Laravel, but ignore some of the values. The column I want to average is set as varchar, but contains either a number between 0 and 10 or the value 'N/A'. I need two averages on this column, one ignoring 'N/A' values, and one counting 'N/A' values as 0. I have the fucntions written how how they would be to calculate the averages but I am hoping to get some input on the best way to do this.

I would love to be able to call these functions like this:

```
    $web_scored_tq = $website->scored_tq;
    $web_uscored_tq = $website->unscored_tq;
```

Functions:

```
public function scored_tq() {
    $valid_click_ads = $this->valid_click_ads;
    $total = 0;
    $num = 0;

    foreach ($valid_click_ads as $valid_click_ad) {
        if ($valid_click_ad->tq != "N/A") {
            $total += $valid_click_ad->tq;
            ++$num;
        }
    }

    $scored_tq = $total / $num;
}

public function unscored_tq() {
    $valid_click_ads = $this->valid_click_ads;
    $total = 0;
    $num = 0;

    foreach ($valid_click_ads as $valid_click_ad) {
        if ($valid_click_ad->tq != "N/A") {
            $total += $valid_click_ad->tq;
            ++$num;
        } else {
            ++$num;
        }
    }

    $unscored_tq = $total / $num;
}
```

Comment: SQL query is the best way to solve your problem. Idea: SELECT sum( without N/A) as total_without_na, count(*) as count FROM TABLE. SELECT sum( IF COLUMN = "N/A" , 0 , COLUMN) as total, count( * ) as count FROM TABLE; these two queries will help you.

Comment: @TurtleBo I assume, that you have these functions, in your website Model, with properly set, Eloquent relationship to valid_click_ads, but I don't understand, why they don't have any `return ...`. And BTW for the sake of db performance, it would be much better to change, tq column to integer, and consequently `N/A` to `-1`. Of course, I don't know, if it is possible in your case...

Comment: Bart! Thank you! I will make sure to structure my data this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found laravel's model getFooAttribute! I used this to add the following functions to my Website model, and now can call $website->scored_tq or $website->unscored_tq.

```
public function getScoredTqAttribute() {
    $valid_click_ads = $this->valid_click_ads;
    $total = 0;
    $num = 0;

    foreach ($valid_click_ads as $valid_click_ad) {
        if ($valid_click_ad->tq != -1) {
            $total += $valid_click_ad->tq;
            ++$num;
        }
    }

    if ( $num != 0 ) {
        $scored_tq = $total / $num;
    } else {
        $scored_tq = '-';
    }
    return $scored_tq;
}

public function getUnscoredTqAttribute() {
    $valid_click_ads = $this->valid_click_ads;
    $total = 0;
    $num = 0;

    foreach ($valid_click_ads as $valid_click_ad) {
        if ($valid_click_ad->tq != -1) {
            $total += $valid_click_ad->tq;
        }
        ++$num;
    }

    if ( $num != 0 ) {
        $unscored_tq = $total / $num;
    } else {
        $unscored_tq = '-';
    }
    return $unscored_tq;
}
```

I also changed how my data is structured to integers, where "N/A" values are changed to -1.